# Harmonic Series is $\theta(\ln n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration

How does one prove that $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} = H_n = \theta(\ln n)$ by using Riemann Sums? I have seen in the MIT OCW 6.042 that if $f$ is continuous and increasing then $$f(1) + \int_1^n f(x) \, dx  < f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(n) < f(n) + \int_1^n f(x) \, dx$$ But besides the intuition behind it, I do not know how to prove it. It can be obviously used here to prove my question about harmonic series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, $$f(k)<\int_k^{k+1} f(x)\;dx<f(k+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to consider the function $f(x) = 1/x$. You can bound this function from above and below by step functions. For example, you can take the function that is $1/n$ on $[n,n+1]$. It is easy to see that this function is always bigger than $f(x)$, so its integral must be greater. Similarly, you can take the function that is $1/(n+1)$ on $[n,n+1]$. This is clearly always below $f(x)$, so its integral is less. Now, compute the integral of $f(x)$ on $[1,N]$, which is a logarithm, and also compute the integrals of the other two functions, which just become sums.